# OpenShift Pro - Using SSL in Passthrough Mode

Tags: ssl, yaml, openshift

By watching this video [OpenShift Demo Part 13: Using SSL](https://youtu.be/rpT5qwcL3bE) I have managed to get ssl working on my OpenShift Pro web app. But only by using **Edge** Termination Type. I believe **Passthrough** Termination Type is more secure, so I thought I'd try that too.

Unfortunately I cannot get **Passthrough** to work. The video example uses a pre-written template to create the app which I cannot use.

I believe the reason is that I have not specified the certificate and private key in the YAML:

```
spec:
  host: www.bookshop.com
  port:
    targetPort: 8080-tcp
  tbs:
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
    termination: passthrough
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: web
    weight: 100
```

I have created a secret to hold the keystone.jks:

```
oc secrets new ssl-cert-secret /Users/infomedia/Clients/PJLocums/ssl/keystore.jks
```

And created a Service Account that specifies ssl-cert-secret:

```
oc create -f /Users/infomedia/Clients/PJLocums/ssl/ssl-cert-service-account.txt
```

And I'm guessing that one or other of the secret or the service account should be specified in the route YAML.

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What image are you running? Passthrough requires that your application terminates TLS connections and has the required SSL certificates in the image with them being used by the application accepting the connections.

Comment: The image was from boss-webserver30-tomcat8-openshift. When I set up using Edge I pasted the Certificate and RSA Private Key into the route but with passthrough I don't know where to put the cert and key (I have a secret  from the keystore.jks file and a service account that references the secret). I guess that's my question, how do I add the cert and key to my app?